# Date not being formated before being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Example**

I have the following form and table:

Name: |    *Empty*      |

Date: |  *aaaa/mm/dd --:--:--*    |

| Name | Date | Edit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2021-06-27 17:31:05 | *Button here* |

When I press the button in the table, it should display abc on the textbox Name: and 2021-06-27 17:31:05 on the datapicker Date:.

Name: |    abc      |

Date: |  2021-06-27 17:31:05    |

The problem is that i want this format to the date 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss' but probably because i rarely work with JavaScript or jQuery and don't know much about these languages what i did might make no sense and ended up not working.

**Code (simplified for the question)**

```
$(".btneditfatura").click( e =>{
  let textvalues = displayDataFatura(e);
  let id = $("input[name*='idfatura']");
  let data = $("input[name*='datafatura']");

  id.val(textvalues[0]);
  data.val(textvalues[1].toString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'));

function displayDataFatura(e) {
  let id = 0;
  const td = $("#tbody tr td");
  let textvalues = [];

  for (const value of td){
      if(value.dataset.id == e.target.dataset.id){
         textvalues[id++] = value.textContent;
      }
  }
  return textvalues;
}
```

Library: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Warning: The specified value "2021-06-27 17:31:05" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Comment: which library are you using? please share its link

Comment: @sid library added.

Comment: So what output are you getting? Or are you getting an error? Add those details if possible.

Comment: @TusharShahi Warning added. Everything else is displayed correctly except the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to normalize your code using jQuery since the question is tagged as jQuery and you start your listener that way. If you want it in vanilla, just let me know.

A couple things to note: jQuery methods are incompatible with ES6 arrow functions, so just use the normal `function(){` callback. Otherwise, to find things relative to the button, you can use `$(this).closest(selector).find(selector).eq(index of target)`

To get the value for the `datetime-local` input, (in this case) you just need to shimmy your current value into that format (just putting a T in the middle)

```js
$(".btneditfatura").click(function() {
  let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
  let dateref = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
  dateref =dateref.split(" ").join("T")
  $("input[name*='idfatura']").val(id)
  $("input[name*='datafatura']").val(dateref)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>2021-06-27 17:31:05</td>
    <td><button class='btneditfatura'>Click</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type='id' name='idfatura' /><input type="datetime-local" step="1"  name='datafatura' />
```

Comment: The last thing you said I already know but that's not the problem. On HTML code, write this `<input type="datetime-local" step="1" name="datafatura" />`  and you'll see that your resolution doesn't work anymore, and that's my problem.

Comment: @krilldrop- answer updated  to accommodate datetime-local. Did that solve the question?